# Why would you set the Package Configurations in SSIS VS over SSMS Run Time?

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, ssms

If you can set the Configuration Files in the Execute Package Utilty in SSMS, is there a reason to set it up in Visual Studio SSIS beforehand?

I've been trying to set up the configuration in an XML file which I've set in the Package Configurations Organizer in SSIs. I've set it up to run from the Envrionment variable. Wouldn't it be better to just configure the Configurations from the SSMS in the Execute Package Utility Wizard and add the file in?

Answer (score 1):

Visual studio is your 'design time' settings. When you are running your package in visual studio, you have to get your configurations from *somewhere*. YOU can't get the from the execute package utility.  That's why you set them in Visual Studio. When you deploy the package they are overriden with 'runtime' settings which you might set in various ways.